# ASP.Net C# (Get A Color (RED) Pixel Position In An Image (PNG)) Returns Wrong X, Y Co-oridinates

Tags: c#

In my project I need to find the `X` and `Y` position of a red dot (pixel) in PNG image files. There will be only 1 red dot (pixel) (RGB - 255, 0, 0) in the PNG file as per the condition.

Following is the code I have written; in some cases, it returns the wrong X, Y position. The wrong X, Y position is cross-checked in PhotoShop. Kindly help me know; what is wrong in the code or am I missing something.

```
protected void GetRedPixelCoordinates(HttpPostedFile postedFile)
{
    try
    {
        Bitmap image1 = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(postedFile.InputStream);

        //System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat pform = image1.PixelFormat;

        int xPos = 0;
        int yPos = 0;

        for (xPos = 0; xPos < image1.Width - 1; xPos++)
        {
            for (yPos = 0; yPos < image1.Height - 1; yPos++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = image1.GetPixel(xPos, yPos);

                if (pixelColor.R == 255 && pixelColor.G == 0 && pixelColor.B == 0)
                {
                    lblRedDotTop.Text = xPos.ToString().Trim() + " Pixels";
                    lblRedDotLeft.Text = yPos.ToString().Trim() + " Pixels";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

The image I am trying to process is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z8BsSFX3rQVXek4lYIivzhFfiuQSxor_/view?usp=sharing). It is a PNG image with transparency.

Comment: when you say in some circumstances it returns wrong, what is the ratio of right : wrong?

Comment: Note that this will give you the *last* red pixel in the image because you never quit out of your loops.

Comment: How do you know it is wrong?

Comment: Hi @SimonPrice, have not checked for ratio particularly.

Comment: @DavidG the original code has a break in IF bracket; I just missed to write here.

Comment: So you posted an unanswerable question, next time please take more care when posting here.

Comment: @PeterSmith I think I am missing something as the code fails to return X,Y position of Red Dot pixel in some case of few files.

Comment: Note that your edit still doesn't give you the first red pixel because you only break out of the first `for` loop, but the outer one keeps going.

Comment: Hi @DavidG in the details I have tried to explain that as per code condition there will be only 1 red dot (pixel) in the uploaded image file; hence this code is supposed to return any first occurrence of the red dot. Some images were not returning the proper X, Y position of the pixel which was cross checked in PhotoShop. This is a Asp.Net application; where processed information is stored on server. Kindly help me to phrase the question properly if I am missing detailing.

Comment: OK, but since you didn't supply an actual image to test with, how can we guess what the problem is?

Comment: `some images were not returning the proper X,Y position`  What _was_ at that position (did you confirm that it was, in fact, not red)?  Was that position before or after the one that was reported?  Did you confirm the "red dot" was actually 255,0,0?  What about the Alpha value?

Comment: Oh @DavidG (I am so sorry to miss sharing the file). Please check the file at the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z8BsSFX3rQVXek4lYIivzhFfiuQSxor_/view?usp=sharing

The RedDot is placed at Postion 1000/1000 while the code returns X,Y position as 937/987

Comment: And what output do you expect to get, versus what output you actually get?

Comment: @DavidG the code returns X,Y position as 937/987 while the correct X/Y position is 1000/1000

Comment: You are not checking alpha levels, there's lots of red pixels in that image but they are transparent. Do this: `if (pixelColor.R == 255 && pixelColor.G == 0 && pixelColor.B == 0 && pixelColor.A == 255)`

Comment: @WonkotheSane the reddot pixel position in the image is confirmed with PhotoShop (which is at 1000/1000 Top-Left); while the code returns X/Y postion as 937/987.

Yes the the RGB values of red dot is also confirmed as RGB(255,0,0)

Comment: @DavidG HOLA... MAGIC... It worked... Thanks A Ton... I also learnt how to phrase a question in detail. Thanks A Ton Again. (Hope I could mark it as answer to my very first question on StackOverFlow)

Comment: Your question has been closed now, so no answers can be added.

Comment: @DavidG: I've voted to reopen the question.  If reopened, the OP should update the question to include a link to the test image, and you could add an appropriate answer.  (And glad it was the alpha value, as I expected) :)

Comment: You still need one more reopen vote for me to add an answer.

Comment: @DavidG Reopened!

Comment: `for (xPos = 0; xPos < image1.Width - 1; xPos++)` - it skips last column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image actually contains lots of red pixels, but most of them have an alpha value of 0 meaning they are transparent. You need to check for this in your code like this:

```
if (pixelColor.R == 255 && 
    pixelColor.G == 0 && 
    pixelColor.B == 0 && 
    pixelColor.A == 255)
{
    // snip
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you never break out of the loop, you will keep looking for every red pixel until the image has been completely parsed.   Then you will be left with the last red pixel as the coords.

Assuming you only want the first red pixel, you should break out of the loop when you find it:

```
    protected void GetRedPixelCoordinates(HttpPostedFile postedFile)
    {
        try
        {
            Bitmap image1 = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(postedFile.InputStream);

            //System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat pform = image1.PixelFormat;

            int xPos = 0;
            int yPos = 0;
            bool found = false; <--  HERE

            for (xPos = 0; xPos < image1.Width - 1 && !found; xPos++) <-- HERE
            {
                for (yPos = 0; yPos < image1.Height - 1 && !found; yPos++) <-- HERE
                {
                    Color pixelColor = image1.GetPixel(xPos, yPos);

                    if (pixelColor.R == 255 && pixelColor.G == 0 && pixelColor.B == 0)
                    {
                        lblRedDotTop.Text = xPos.ToString().Trim() + " Pixels";
                        lblRedDotLeft.Text = yPos.ToString().Trim() + " Pixels";
                        found = true; <-- HERE
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ugh, putting the flag check in the for loop is kinda awful and makes it really hard to read. If one of my devs came to me with that, I would send them back to rewrite it. Secondly, and more importantly, we are not sure this is the answer as the question is so poorly defined.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that after I'd written it.

Comment: Hi Neil; On getting the required pixel (red Color) in the if bracket I am actually breaking the loop already; just missed to mention here as the original code is bit different

Comment: So your question is unclear AND you haven't posted the actual code?

Comment: My question is clear; the actual code contains lots of TEXT settings which I have cleared from this posted code